# Apache Spark Streaming - reduceByKey, groupByKey, aggregateByKey or combineByKey?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an application which generates multiple sessions each containing multiple events (in Avro format) over a 10 minute time period - each event will include a session id which could be used to find all the session data. Once I have gathered all this data I would like to then create a single session object.

My plan is to use a window in Spark Streaming to ensure I have the data available in memory for processing - unless there are any other suggestions which would be a good fit to solve my problem.

After reading the Apache Spark documentation it looks like I could achieve this using various different API's, but I am struggling to work out which one would be the best fit for my problem - so far I have come across reduceByKey / groupByKey / aggregateByKey / combineByKey.

To give you a bit more detail into the session / event data I expect there to be anywhere in the region of 1m active sessions with each session producing 5/10 event in a 10 minute period.

It would be good to get some input into which approach is a good fit for gathering all session events and producing a single session object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you ensure you have all the data ready? Meaning how do you ensure that streaming has stopped? 

reduceByKey, groupBykey etc. are grouping techniques, another questions, what are you trying to group?

Comment: Each session will contain a "complete" event type which will signal the end of a session. In addition, the start session event will contain a timestamp which will be used as a cut off (e.g. maximum session time of 10 mins), so if the session complete event has not been received I can still process all the data available. Does that make sense?

Comment: In terms of grouping; each session will generate multiple client events (in Avro format) linked by the same session id. I am trying to collect all client events belonging to the same session in order to create a single session object which can be used for further processing / reporting. Once I have all the session data then I plan to store this in HDFS meaning that it can then be removed from Spark Streaming as no further processing will be required. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@phillip Thanks for the details. Let's go in the details of each keys:

(1). groupByKey - It can help to rank, sort and even aggregate using any key. Performance wise it is slower because does not use combiner.
groupByKey() is just to group your dataset based on a key

If you are doing any aggregation like sum, count, min, max then this is not preferable.

(2). reduceBykey - It supports only aggregations like sum, mix, max. Uses combiner so faster than groupbykey. Data shuffled is very less.
reduceByKey() is something like grouping + aggregation.
reduceByKey can be used when we run on large data set.

(3). aggregateByKey - Similar to reduceBykey, It supports only aggregations like sum, mix, max. is logically same as reduceByKey() but it lets you return result in different type. In another words, it lets you have a input as type x and aggregate result as type y. For example (1,2),(1,4) as input and (1,”six”) as output

I believe you require only grouping and no aggregations, then I believe you are left with no choice then to use groupBykey()

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response - I agree that using groupByKey() might be the best fit for my problem. Out of interest, would there be any advantage using the other API’s allowing me to combine all session events into a collection (e.g. List<SessionEvent>) on each cluster instance before processing to create my final Session object? Or, would this approach fail to provide any real performance benefits or just not an option at all?